# what is the proper way of define workflow requirements?

Tags: 2011, workflow

We are in the process of building workflow. Since I am not an expert in workflow, I am wondering what is the proper way to define the workflow requirements? If would be extremely helpful if someone can provide a sample workflow requirements.

Comment: Charles, I'm afraid this is a very broad topic and can't be explained, shown or designed in StackExchange question/answer format. Rather, more thorough and methodical approach is needed. Please shoot me an email, if you would like to proceed on that path.

Comment: I understand this is a huge topic, but there must be some basic principles which applies. I didn't see a lot of discussion on this, blogs, articles, etc. It would be helpful if someone can give me a few links to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should approach SDL Tridion workflow requirements like any other business analysis requirements including documentation, diagrams, and descriptions.

### Documentation Contents

Just like a Tridion Functional Design (or any BRD/FRD), consider including the following.

- Problem or Opportunity Statement (as input)
- Business requirements based on what your Business Analysts capture
- User requirements that you know of
- Supporting diagrams

If using SDL Tridion 2013, you could also consider an object-oriented approach in the technical design. See Eric Huiza's posts for examples:

- [Implementing a Class Design](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/08/developing-sdl-tridion-2013-workflows.html)
- [Taking it a step further with Dependency Injections](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2013/11/tridion-workflow-developing-using_26.html) (2013 SP1)

Be sure to start with the business requirements though--not all content "workflow" requirements are actually Tridion workflow (i.e. automation and authorization can solve a few scenarios that *look* like workflow).

### Diagrams

SDL Tridion workflow includes a subset of the standard flowchart conventions including:

- Decisions in diamonds
- Actions in boxes
- Start and stop symbols (slightly different in Tridion)

*Tridion just adds a distinction between manual and automated steps.*

Your supporting diagrams can be in the form of swim lanes (sequence diagrams) or a flow chart and they don't need to be in Tridion's visio format. I'd argue you wouldn't want to start with Tridion's format as this can bias your actual use cases.

### Descriptions

Like any other Tridion documentation, a diagram is never enough. Your page and content type diagrams (starting with wireframes) nor a BluePrint (Structure) Design diagram give enough context to know what to build. So you'll want corresponding documentation on what should happen at each step. Paragraphs, tables, or use cases work.

It's up to your team to use diagramming conventions they're familiar with. Something "UML-like" is probably enough. I like [UML Distilled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321193687)'s view which recognizes the formal UML standard as well as the need to be practical with "UML as a sketch." I've yet to work with a customer that stuck with official UML standards (though I've had colleagues suggest steady state diagrams).

The final step from business and system requirements to the actual Visio Workflow Process design and code does take Tridion knowledge, but the bulk of the design process depends on what your team needs.

I'd recommend the Automation training for that knowledge, but my colleagues and I just finished a **Workflow Design course** that we should be posting shortly which features examples, tips, and specific scenarios to help with the design part.

Comment: Thanks Alvin, please update us when the course is ready. I can't wait to see it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a 'proper way' in, it's a huge combination of business / technology requirements, plus there's a huge number of implmentation options around SDL Tridion Workflow.

If you've not undertaken the SDL training program I'd highly recommend it, I see one of their classes is tailored towards workflow 'Experience Manager & Workflow 2013' you can see the courses here: http://www.sdl.com/services/education-certification/training-product/web-content-management/